# Apache Superset config.py on

Tags: macos, terminal, anaconda, apache-superset, pythonpath

I am trying to customising my **Apache Superset**. I am not very familiar with Terminal.

On the [documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) it is written:
*"To configure your application, you need to create a file (module) **superset_config.py** and make sure it is in your PYTHONPATH. Here are some of the parameters you can copy / paste in that configuration module:"*.

Let's say I want to decrease ROW_LIMIT to 5000, and my Superset is installed on an Anaconda Environment called "ExperimentSuperset".

Can someone please explain to me what do I have to do to reach this results?

Answer (score 12):

The pythonpath is mainly defined by:

1. execution directory
2. pythonpath environemnt variable
3. default install dir for modules

(Also it can be enhanced using sys.path and pth file - which definesdirectories and itself needs to be in python).

To my experience, pythonpath variable is set by most superset applications and can be evaluated the simplest way by calling `set` in console or `echo $pythonpath`. You can also use python to print out the pythonpath from terminal: `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`.

Superset looks in the path for a file called `superset_config.py` there. You can also directly point to the file even if it is not in the path when you set the environment variable `SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/your/path/to/superset_config.py`.

In the sources there's a file called `config.py` that has all settings. All settings there will be overwritten with the settings loaded from `superset_config.py`. So you just need to define the specifics of your superset application.

So your specific steps are:

1. create a new and empty `superset_config.py`
2. add `ROW_LIMIT = 5000` to file
3. make sure it's in python path or set environment variable `SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH`

Superset will then use the config file and read your settings. Noite the config is a fully functional python file, so you can add methods etc. In the superset example there's a useful method pulling parameters in from environment variables. This is especially useful when using e.g. Docker.

Answer (score 6):

At the end of `config.py`, you'll see that it tries to load `superset_config.py` from the `SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable, so all you need to do is:

1. Create the file
2. Set the values you want there (ROW_LIMIT = 5000)
3. Run this command:

```
export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/your/superset_config.py
```

4. Restart your superset to take the changes

Source: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/2117#issuecomment-277666183

Answer (score 1):

Configure your **superset_config.py** to override the default parameters of superset which is declared in **config.py** file -

superset_config.py:

```
ROW_LIMIT=5000
```

If you are running your docker image with **docker run** command then it might not work. Because **superset_config.py** only execute if there is **SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH** in **os.environ**. You need to add the **SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH** in Dockerfile so that it will be picked up from **os.environ**.

To achieve this you need to configure your Dockerfile like this, add **SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH** with ENV:

Dockerfile:

```
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    FLASK_ENV=production \
    SUPERSET_ENV=production \
    SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes \
    CYPRESS_CONFIG=false \
    MAPBOX_API_KEY='XXXXXX' \
    FLASK_APP="superset.app:create_app()" \
    PYTHONPATH="/app/pythonpath:/app/docker/pythonpath_prod" \
    SUPERSET_HOME="/app/superset_home" \
    SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH="/path/to/your/superset_config.py" \
    SUPERSET_PORT=8088
```

For example my file is available at /app/docker/superset_config.py then this will my **SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH**.

Now build new image using Dockerfile.

You can check your image **Env** config by this command.

```
docker inspect <image-name:tag>
```

For any query please comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be:

Have customized `superset_config.py` file in current directory.

example `superset_config.py`

```
ROW_LIMIT = 5000
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT = 9777
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///superset.sqlite3'
```

We don't need to export environment variable `SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH`. Instead we can call our intended actions with modified `PYTHONPATH`

For example:

```
PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH superset db upgrade

# or
PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked some time ago but I found myself in the same situation recently and would like to offer my input if it will help someone else. As of the current date to be able to make edits to the configuration you have to create a file named "superset_config.py" and place it in the pythonpath. One of the default python path for apache/superset is "/app/pythonpath".

In the docker run command, specify a volume on your localhost that is linked to the container using the -v option, for example, `docker run --network <your_network_name> --detach --name <name_of_your_container> -v /<path_to_local_volume>:/app/pythonpath/ -e  "SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY=<YOUR_SECRET_KEY> --restart=unless-stopped -p 8088:8088 apache/superset:<version_tag>`. The other options declared in the run is is not mandatory and only depend on if you want to declare those values. PS. You specify additional PYTHONPATH by setting the environment variable option -e `-e PYTHONPATH=</path/to/your/python/modules>`.

Answer (score -2):

If the installation was done with the instructions from ["installing from scratch"](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch), the `config.py` will be somewhere similar to:
`/root/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/config.py`

Comment: Please explain your answer.